# VF Page return Matching List Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList

Tags: button, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am trying to return a list of records from Project_Join__c that have a value in the Field number__c that matches the value in the record where I click the button that calls the vf page. I am getting the Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.number__c error when i try to save the page.

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller_ProjectJoin_Match{

//Set Booleans
    public boolean showNumber {get; set;}

//Passing parameter from button to class
    String pnumber= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('num');

    public string PassedNum ='';p
    Project_Join__c pj1 = [select number__c from Project_Join__c where number__c =: pnumber limit 1];

    public List<Project_Join__c> projectJoin{get; set;}

    public Controller_ProjectJoin_Match(){
        passedNum = pj1.number__c;
        showNumber = true;
            if (pnumber != ''){
                projectJoin = [SELECT Number__c FROM Project_Join__c WHERE number__c =: passedNum];}
   } 
}
```

**PAGE:**

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Project Join matching list:">
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projectJoin}" var="projectJoin">

         <apex:column headerValue="Number" rendered="{!showNumber}">
         <apex:outputField value="{!projectJoin.number__c}"/>

     </apex:column> 
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

**Button:**

```
/apex/Controller_ProjectJoin_Match?num={!Project_Join__c.Number__c}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pageBlockTable var attribute is the name of object in the list and not the list itself so it would be a good idea to give it a different name. Like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projectJoin}" var="projectJoinObj">
```

And then you can reference it inside pageBlockTable

```
<apex:outputField value="{!projectJoinObj.number__c}"/>
```